# Different Token in Testflight and xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm testing my new application in Testflight right now, but when I launch my app in Testflight another UID token appears in my database. When I open my app in xcode another UID token is showing up.

I'm trying to test push notifications in Testflight but the token which is sent to my database (when I run the app in Testflight) doesn't work (it's another one then in xcode). But the token which one is sent when I run the app in xcode works.

Does anyone know why the token is different when I run my app Testflight? Cannot test the pushnotifications with the UID token which appears in my database after I opened the app in testflight.

But when I run the UID token from xcode I receive a pushnotification.

Comment: What do you mean by "launch my app in Testflight" ?

Comment: @A-Live i mean upload it to Testflight an let my testers run the app.

Comment: So you are able to run the app on your tester's devices with Xcode, right ?